# Baffled by indexed db delete

Tags: indexeddb, delete-record

My scenario:

I have an indexed db database page that retrieves multiple files (pictures) with a 'delete file' button next to each picture.  In addition, there are check boxes next to each picture for multiple files to be deleted.  The 'Delete File' button calls a 'deleteRecord' function and passes it the key...it deletes the file just fine.  However, when the mass delete button calls this same 'deleteRecord' function for mass deletion and passes it the key no files are deleted.  The 'deleteRecord' runs through each key and has an onsuccess event.  However, nothing gets deleted?

> deleteFile function (this works with the individual buttons):

```
function deleteRecord (id) {
    console.log('inside deleteRecord.  id: ' + id);
    var transaction = db.transaction("patient", "readwrite");
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("patient");
    var request = objectStore.delete(id);
    request.onsuccess = function(evt) {
    console.log("It's gone!");
};
```

It's being successfully called from:

```
inputBttn.onclick = function () {
    var prompt = 'Are you sure you want to delete this record?'
    answer = confirm(prompt);
    if (answer) {
    deleteRecord(key);
    console.log('Key = ' + key + ' Record Deleted');
}
```

and unsuccessfully from:

```
function massDelete() {
    console.log('inside massDelete');
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('c1');                  
    var prompt = 'You are about to delete Multiple Records.  Are you sure?'
    var answer = confirm(prompt);
    if (answer) {
    console.log('Delete confirmed...starting mass delete');
    for (var x = 0; x < checkboxes.length; x++) {
        if (checkboxes[x].checked) {
        var key = checkboxes[x].value;
        console.log('checkbox value = ' + key);
        deleteRecord (key);
    }
};
```

Any explanations as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you get this working?  Are your ids strings or numbers?  The ids used for `.delete(id)` must match the type used to create the ids.

Answer (score 2):

I searched around for a long time to get an answer to this after trying the code here, which is interestingly not marked as a solution. Kyaw Tun's answer didn't work for me, but gave me some ideas. So, despite the fact that this is an old thread, I'll post a complete solution that actually works, since I couldn't find anything on the web that solved this pretty common problem. My solution is in backbone, so there's a little bit of context (mainly the `this` reference) that can easily be ignored:

```
deleteFromDb: function(keys, callback) {
    var _this = this,
        request = indexedDB.open(_this.LOCAL_DB, _this.DB_VERSION);

    request.onsuccess = function(event) {
        var db = event.target.result,
            tx = db.transaction([_this.URL_TABLE], "readwrite"),
            store = tx.objectStore(_this.URL_TABLE),
            recursiveDelete;

        recursiveDelete = function(_index) {
            var deleteRequest;

            // base case
            if (_index >= keys.length) {
                callback();
                return;
            }   
            deleteRequest = store.delete(keys[_index]);
            deleteRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
                recursiveDelete(_index + 1); 
            }   
        }   
        recursiveDelete(0);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code. Some suggestions:

1. In deleteRecord, add a handler to transaction for the complete and abort events, see which one gets fired:

   ```
   transaction.onabort = function(e) { console.log("abort"); };
   transaction.oncomplete = function(e) { console.log("complete"); };
   ```
2. deleteRecord is missing a closing brace, so it's probably not the actual code that you are working with. If you have further trouble, consider uploading a reduced version of your code to jsfiddle.
3. Which browsers have you tried this on?  Do they all exhibit the same behavior?

Edit:
Where does `key` come from in `inputBttn.onclick`? Are you sure `massDelete` is passing the correct value to `deleteRecord`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only use this program in Chrome.  The APIs that create the database and photos are only supported by Chrome, at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks OK, however I will avoid async loop by:

```
function deleteRecords (ids) {    
  var transaction = db.transaction("patient", "readwrite");
  var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("patient");
  var id = ids.shift();
  var request = objectStore.delete(id);
  request.onsuccess = function(evt) {
    console.log(id + " deleted");
    if (ids.length > 0) {
      id = ids.shift();
      objectStore.delete(id);
    }
  }
  request.onerror = function(evt) {
    console.log(id + " delete fail");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the MDN an object store can only have a single "read/write" transaction open at any given time. The loop would be attempting to open multiple "read/write" transactions on top of each other, which is likely causing the failure. I assume the same limitation is present in Chrome. The solution by Kyaw Tun should work in preventing the multiple "read/write" transactions, although you shouldn't need to keep re-opening transactions.

[Link To IDBTransaction MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBTransaction)

Answer (score 0):

1. When trying to delete multiple records, make sure that the **transaction remains active**. With respect to this Marshall's answer is correct.
2. Another issue I faced while deleting records was, determining if the key is numeric or string. If you are using the wrong **typeof key**, the record may not get deleted.